# Super-resolution of license plate in video sequence

Tags: opencv

This is a follow up question to my question here: [Local enhancing of license plate in video sequence](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715908/local-enhancing-of-license-plate-in-video-sequence)

I implemented a basic super-resolution technique suggested by the answer, but I am having trouble obtaining better resolution results. I trimmed the video sequence to 40 frames as seen below:[image]

and using the code below, which takes the first 5 frames and performs Super-resolution, then the super-resolved frame is repeatedly updated with the processing of the rest of the frames in the sequence:

```
public void Process(Image<Gray, byte> frame)
    {
        SetRegionOfInterest(frame);

        var resizedFrame = ResizeFrame(frame);

        InputFrames.Add(resizedFrame);
        if(InputFrames.Count > 5)
        {
            InputFrames.RemoveAt(0);
            PerformSuperResolution();
        }
    }

    public void PerformSuperResolution()
    {
        // WindowSize = 5
        var referenceFrame = InputFrames[WindowSize-1].Convert<Gray, byte>();
        var featuresToTrack = referenceFrame.GoodFeaturesToTrack(100, 0.1, 5, 10);

        referenceFrame.FindCornerSubPix(featuresToTrack, new Size(WindowSize,WindowSize), new Size(-1,-1), new MCvTermCriteria(20, 0.03d));

        var resultFrame = InputFrames[WindowSize-1].Convert<Gray, double>();
        for(var frameCounter = 0; frameCounter < WindowSize-1; frameCounter++)
        {
            // Get shift between frames
            var shiftResult = GetShiftResult(InputFrames[frameCounter],referenceFrame, featuresToTrack);

            // Warp to correct shift
            var warpMatrix = new Matrix<double>(new[,] { {1, 0, -shiftResult.ShiftX}, {0, 1, -shiftResult.ShiftY}, {0, 0, 1}});

            var warpedFrame = InputFrames[frameCounter].WarpPerspective(warpMatrix, 
                INTER.CV_INTER_NN, 
                WARP.CV_WARP_DEFAULT, 
                new Gray(0)); 

            resultFrame.RunningAvg(warpedFrame.Convert<Gray,double>(), 1, resultFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>());
        }
        SuperResolutionFrame = resultFrame.Convert<Gray, byte>();
    }

    public ShiftResult GetShiftResult(Image<Gray, byte> inputFrame, Image<Gray, byte> referenceFrame, PointF[][] ActualFeature)
    {
        var result = new ShiftResult();

        PointF[] NextFeature;
        Byte[] Status;
        float[] TrackError;

        // optical flow
        OpticalFlow.PyrLK(referenceFrame, inputFrame, ActualFeature[0], 
            new Size(WindowSize, WindowSize), 5, new MCvTermCriteria(20, 0.1d), 
            out NextFeature, out Status, out TrackError);

        //get displacements
        float[] XdisplacementVectors = new float[NextFeature.Length];
        float[] YdisplacementVectors = new float[NextFeature.Length];
        for(int i = 0; i < NextFeature.Length; i++)
        {
            XdisplacementVectors[i] = NextFeature[i].X - ActualFeature[0][i].X;
            YdisplacementVectors[i] = NextFeature[i].Y - ActualFeature[0][i].Y;
        }

        // gets average of displacements (disregards outliers)
        result.ShiftX = getAVG(XdisplacementVectors);
        result.ShiftY = getAVG(YdisplacementVectors);

        return result;
    }
```

where the program calls `Process(frame)` on an array of input video frames (totaling 40) as such:

```
for(int i  = 0; i < image_array.Count; i++)
{
    Res.Process(image_array[i]);
}
```

and I obtained this resulting image:
[image]

As you can see there are only small improvements in the overall resolution, and not much improvement to the readability of the license plate. I've tried experimenting with the various parameters, but the parameters used above seem to be the best I can do.

I am open to any suggestions for improvement (need not be limited to the use of C#/Emgu CV as above), and even different approaches in implementation, if possible within the realm of mobile applications.

Comment: What specific algorithm does this use to calculate optical flow? If the accuracy for optical flow is poor, varying the other parameters won't help much.

Comment: I am using OpenCV's PyrLK (iterative Lucas-Kanade method with pyramids), as seen in GetShiftResult in the code above. I use it to find the displacements from one frame to the next and disregard outliers, but I am trying to figure out how to determine if the accuracy of the optical flow I'm using is poor or not. I did trim the video to what is seen above to get mostly translational motion, and the lighting does not change much so PyrLK should theoretically be reasonably accurate.

Comment: Have you solved your problem ? Can you share the solution in this case ?

Answer (score 1):

Super resolution problem is ill-posed CV problem and no satisfying solutions yet since it contains more "information" in the output than input.

However in some very specific situations, we have a strong prior assumptions on what image we are dealing with, some methods can get better results than a general problem.

As of state-of-the-art, we have some codes available:

[License Super Resolution](https://github.com/zzxvictor/License-super-resolution)

Answer (score 0):

I understand this question was asked long time ago. However now it's possible to use opencv for Image Super Resolution with some of the state of the art models like EDSR.

Follow this links for full implementation
https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2020/11/09/opencv-super-resolution-with-deep-learning/
https://learnopencv.com/super-resolution-in-opencv/

Comment: both links are for single image superresolution, which is not what OP wants